# Prompt for credentials in a c# cmdlet test project

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a way to prompt for a `PSCredential` in the `Initialize` method of a C# test project?

I'd use PowerShell's `Get-Credential` Cmdlet, but I'm not sure how to call it from within the Cmdlet's class.

If that's not possible, prompting for a `SecureString` would be acceptable.

**Edit**
I need the `username` and `password` properties to pass to a system (SAP BI) that doesn't currently support single sign-on.

Comment: have you checked this link - http://incoherenttruth.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/execute-powershell-cmdlets-from-asp-net-with-user-impersonation/

Comment: You would be better off adding a required parameter of the right type. If not supplied then PSH will prompt for it. Compare the `-Credential` parameter of `Start-Job`.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2016-09-01%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/security/CredentialCommands.cs#L96)?